# Excel 2007 Bar Char - Wrap X-Axis Labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am not able to wrap the text of x-axis labels on an excel 2007 bar PivotChart. As a result, the axis labels are overlapping onto eachother. Does anyone know how can I wrap these labels?

Answer (score 0):

By Bar Chart I assume you mean, a chart with some discrete categories on the Y axis, some continuous value on the X axis, with bars going left-to-right.

If so, you can control how many labels get put on the X axis by right-clicking the X axis and choosing Format Axis..., then for Major Unit choosing Fixed and typing a value larger than the value that was automatically chosen by Excel.

If you can't do this, it might be that your x axis is made of discrete categories rather than numerical values. If so, Bar chart format may not be the best choice for your data. Or, you need a way to express your X axis values as a continuous number rather than discrete values.